# What to check in web project if library exists by error class not found?

Tags: java, class, jar, web, dependencies

I have java web application, that uses hibernate core 3.6.7,
I have check that in WEB-INF/lib exists hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar,

but when I run application (eclipse embedded) I receive error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/hql/ast/tree/LiteralNode
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlASTFactory.getASTNodeType(SqlASTFactory.java:154)
```

I have checked that inside of hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar file exists class org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.LiteralNode.
What next need to check?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have all the needed dependencies of Hibernate also in WEB-INF/lib. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html_single/#hibernate-gsg-setup-releaseBundle for how to know the required dependencies.

Also, read the rest of the stack trace, which should indicate that LiteralNode has not been found because a class it depends on has itself not been found.